# Detect pattern repetition in a file

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I want to make sure a file follows the following pattern:

```
... ... ... foo ... foo_KO ... ... 
... bar ... ... ... ... bar_KO ...
```

The file is extremely long, so, in other words, I want to make sure of the following rule, in `sed` terms:

**Every time ([a-z]*)_KO is matched, there is another field on the same line whose value is \1.**

I hoope I'm clear enough.

I'm on Solaris 10, using ksh.

Example:

**intput**

```
... ... ... foo ... foo_KO ... ... 
... bar ... ... ... ... bar_KO ...
```

**output**

```
valid
```

---

**input**

```
... ... ... foo ... foo_KO ... ... 
... bar ... ... ... ... bar_KO ...
... fubar_KO ... ... ... ... ...
```

**output**

```
invalid line 3
```

or

```
unmatched pattern fubar_KO
```

Comment: The “_KO”-less variant can be anywhere on the same line or only before the one with “_KO”, as in the example?

Comment: It can be anywhere

Comment: What output would you like from the example in your question?

Comment: something like: 'valid'. Let me edit my question with example input and expected outputs

Comment: Can be more than one “_KO”-marked thing in a line?

Comment: Yes, but it's safe to assume that `foo_KO` is unique

Comment: In your example both variants, with and without “_KO” are whole words. Can we base on that? I mean, `awk`'s default splitting will place “foo” and “foo_KO” each in separate fields?

Comment: yes absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will output the line numbers of invalid lines:

```
sed -n '/\([a-z]\+\).*\1_KO/b;/\([a-z]\+\)_KO.*\1/b;=' input_file
```

But not deals with multiple “_KO”'s on one line.

---

This should be more reliable and portable:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if((s=$i)~/^([a-z]+)_KO/){sub(/_KO$/,"",s);o=0;for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)if($j==s)o=1;if(!o)printf"line %d unmatched %s\n",NR,s}}' input_file
```

---

This is trickier, more efficient and supports multiple patterns, but as depends on sorting, locale settings may affect its success:

```
ruby -nae '$F.sort!.select!{|v|v=~/^[a-z]+(_KO)?$/};$F.each_with_index{|v,k|puts"line #{$.} unmatched #{v}"if v[/^([a-z]+)_KO$/]and$F[k-1]!=$1}' input_file
```

---

Basically the same as the above `awk` solution, but looks less verbose in `perl`:

```
perl -nae 'for$k(grep/^[a-z]+_KO$/,@F){print"line $. unmatched $k\n"unless grep{$_ eq substr$k,0,-3}@F}' input_file
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with Solaris `sed`. Here's the error I'm getting: `sed: Label too long: /\([a-z]\+\).*\1_KO/b;/\([a-z]\+\)_KO.*\1/b;=`. I'll try to get my hands on GNU sed, but that's not easy to do around here ...

Comment: The `awk` script worked perfectly thanks. Do not take this the wrong way, but I don't find it very elegant to bruteforce like this manually over each field. I'm sure you agree. There should be a more elegant way to detect if a matched pattern is repeated more than once on a line.

Comment: I agree, it looks quite clumsy. But with multiple patterns _and_ various order I see no simpler way for now.

Comment: @manatwork you are just awesome with awk/sed :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some cryptic perl:

```
perl -ne '/(\w+)_KO\b/ && !/\b$1(?!_KO)\b/ && print "invalid line $.: missing $1\n"' filename
```

`/(\w+)_KO\b/` find the "_KO" word and capture the non-KO part into variable `$1`
`!/\b$1(?!_KO)\b/` is true if there is NO "standalone" word without _KO (`\b` is a word boundary)
If both those conditions are true, print the error message.

To determine if the file is "valid", either

```
output=$(perl -ne '/(\w+)_KO\b/ && !/\b$1(?!_KO)\b/ && print "invalid line $.: missing $!\n"' filename)
[ -z "$output" ] && echo valid
```

or

```
perl -ne '
    BEGIN {$count = 0}
    if (/(\w+)_KO\b/ && !/\b$1(?!_KO)\b/) {print "invalid line $.: missing $!\n"; $count++}
    END {$count == 0 && print "valid\n"}
' filename
```

Comment: Worked pretty well. I did get some false positives though, for words containing _KO inside them. I added a `\b` to your pattern matching regex, as per your explanations. I don't know perl syntax, so if I'm mistaken do not hesitate to re-modify.